# I can't retrieve my custom attributes set in styles.xml when extending MaterialButton

Tags: android, material-components-android

i have a button that extends `MaterialButton` and i’m trying to access custom attributes i defined in `styles.xml`.
But the TypedArray doesnt contain them

Here is my custom style

```
<style name="AppWidget.Button" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
        <item name="android:padding">@dimen/textview_horizontal_padding</item>
        <item name="cornerRadius">24dp</item>
        <item name="android:insetTop">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:insetBottom">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/AppStyle.TextAppearance.Button</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_text</item>
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/button_bg</item>
        <item name="strokeColor">@color/button_stroke</item>
        <item name="strokeWidth">2dp</item>
        <item name="progressWidth">20dp</item>
        <item name="progressColor">@color/dph_teal</item>
</style>
```

My custom attributes are `progressWidth` and `progressColor`

Here is my `attrs.xml`

```
<declare-styleable name="Button">
        <attr name="progressColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="progressWidth" format="dimension" />
</declare-styleable>
```

In my theme I'm setting

```
<item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/AppWidget.Button</item>
```

and how i try to retrieve them

```
private fun init(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) {
        val ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.Button, defStyleAttr, 0)
        try {
            val hasValue1 = ta.hasValue(R.styleable.Button_progressColor) //always false
            val hasValue2 = ta.hasValue(R.styleable.Button_progressWidth) //always false
            progressColor = ta.getColor(R.styleable.Button_progressColor, Color.WHITE)
            progressWidth = ta.getDimension(R.styleable.Button_progressWidth, 5f)
        } finally {
            ta.recycle()
        }
    }
```

Any idea why? I’m basically drawing a progress indicator in the button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to read values set in your default style, you'll need to pass in the correct `defStyleAttr` to your constructor.

To do this, you should also have a constructor which has just the `Context` and `AttributeSet` as arguments. You can call through to your method passing `R.attr.materialButtonStyle` as `defStyleAttr`.

The call to `obtainStyledAttributes` uses the value of `defStyleAttr` to read the default style that is set in your theme.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you forgot to in the Androidmanifest.xml set the style or else it will not be loaded

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppWidget.Button">
```